# What is the typescript type of Mutation list in callback function of mutation observer

Tags: javascript, typescript, callback, mutation-observers

What is the typescript type of `mutationList` in the callback function?

```
const targetNode = document.getElementById("some-id");

const config = { attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true };

const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      console.log("A child node has been added or removed.");
    } else if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
      console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
    }
  }
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(targetNode, config);
```

Comment: Uh, did you try simply inspecting the type declaration?

Comment: Hi, when I searched for the type on google, I didn't find a solution, however I later figured it out myself. So I added it as a Q&A for the sake of people who come to stackoverflow looking for a solution. I think we can do this on [stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.blog/2011/07/01/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Don't google it. Look it up in the [library declarations](https://basarat.gitbook.io/typescript/type-system/lib.d.ts#libdts) that come with your TypeScript, in this case, https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/blob/c61abc9d830c3bc767b42a50e7b8adbba4bf13f0/src/lib/dom.generated.d.ts#L15652

Comment: Thanks for adding, I would like to add my approach to get the type. Hover on MutationObserver in `new MutationObserver` it will show you the type of callback (`MutationCallback`) assign this to your callback function and do `cmd+click` it will take you to the type declaration I mentioned in the answer.

Comment: Yes, that's what I mean - just navigate in your IDE to the type declaration of `MutationObserver` and from there to the type declaration of `MutationCallback`. No need to google it or ask at stackoverflow.

Comment: I can assure you that there will be developers who come searching for this in the future. Let the votes decide 

Comment: It's unlikely they will come searching for this exact type amongst the thousands in the DOM library (and the votes seem to agree on that). A more useful question would have been "***How** do I find the typescript type of a dom function, e.g. MutationObserver?*"

Comment: I don't think we only have 4 developers on Stackoverflow! Too early to come to a conclusion. Yeah, that's a good question. I would be glad to answer if someone asks for it.

Answer (score 1):

### MutationRecord[]

```
const callback = (mutationList: MutationRecord[], observer: MutationObserver) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      console.log("A child node has been added or removed.");
    } else if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
      console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
    }
  }
};
```

or

```
const callback: MutationCallback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
    if (mutation.type === "childList") {
      console.log("A child node has been added or removed.");
    } else if (mutation.type === "attributes") {
      console.log(`The ${mutation.attributeName} attribute was modified.`);
    }
  }
};
```

> Recommended: Assign a type to the callback function instead of assigning it to each of the parameters.

```
interface MutationCallback {
    (mutations: MutationRecord[], observer: MutationObserver): void;
}
```